# Make background transparent after box-shadow

Tags: css

I want to remove the background after hovering an element, (making it transparent)

[Background box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S33Xn.png)

Basically make the shadow override the white background. I've tried setting the background to none, transparent, removing the border and outline, but none work.

```css
a {
  color: rgb(220, 20, 120);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">CLICK ME</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a {
  color: rgb(220, 20, 120);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">CLICK ME</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, before I mark this as the answer is this the exact RGB properties?

Comment: You are welcome! You can specify any color in any format, even in the form in which you had it rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) or rgb(220 20 120) or #db1478. As you wish =)

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  color: rgb(220, 20, 120);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; // FOR SMOOTH HOVER EFFECT
}

a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">CLICK ME</a>
```